# PHP add weekdays not working properly for Friday

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime, weekday

I am trying to add weekdays to a date using the below formula:

```
$date = strtotime($effdate." +5 weekdays");
$date = date('m/d/Y', $date);
```

It works fine for other days but not for Friday. It points to the next Sunday rather than Friday. I googled for many solutions, but didn't get a clear idea.

Is there a workaround to fix this bug?

Comment: [Known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63521), and was supposedly fixed in PHP 5.5

Comment: @Keerthi it may be `2015-06-05`, but what is your php version? are you running this code on 5.5? or are you on an earlier version?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4.0

Answer (score 2):

If you're running PHP < 5.5.0 then this is a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63521) and was fixed in PHP 5.5

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/L6tjt)

The bug report does provide an alternative function that will work with versions of PHP that are susceptible to this bug, though it's using DateTime objects rather than unix timestamps

Comment: Is there a way to do it in 5.4? Or upgrade is the only option?